# Claiming my Iota Balance

Tags: snapshot, iota-recovery

I have used the reclaim tool in the past to get my IOTA back and now its gone again.I just realized today that there was a snapshot. When i log onto my updated IOTA wallet my balance is 0. When I try following the guide, one of the steps is to go under RECEIVE and generate a new address. I do not have that option, I only have attach to TONGLE and under history, I have 2 addresses.

Please help me claim my IOTA safely.

Comment: Without any specific information this will be very hard to answer. Also this is not an IOTA support forum. This is a Q&A site about IOTA.

Answer (score 0):

Attach your address to the tangle, then you will get an option to generate one more address.

You will have to generate as many addresses as you had done transactions with the seed.

In case you are using the beta Trinity wallet, it has a "Snapshot Recovery" function that will automate this for you (and it will suggest so automatically if you add a new seed and it has a zero balance).